# How to include Vuforia iOS framework into ionic project

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, cocoapods, vuforia

I would like to include the sample xcode project functionality provided by Vuforia in an ionic project. The sample project can be downloaded from here: https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples

The standalone project works fine, I was able to to tweak it to meet my expectations regarding the functionality.

The problems started when I was trying to integrate it into my main project, which uses ionic framework.

Basically the project works like this:

- I have an application in ionic's webview
- There's a button which leads to the AR functionality
- I have implemented a capacitor plugin to launch a native view which uses Vuforia

I was able to finish the Android version, so it's out of scope.

The sample XCode project adds a bunch of things to the Build phases in order to embed the VuforiaEngine.framework and link, compile the C++ sources for the bridge between the Swift source and the Framework

First problem: the ionic project uses CocoaPods for the XCode project, so even if I set everything in the "App" project (build phases), it was ignored by the workspace settings. If I build the App project it cannot import the Pods, if I build the Pods project it does not have the necessary settings.

So next, I tried to create a custom Pod to include the framework, add necessary settings and import it.

First it was promising, but after a while I ran into weird error messages and I have no idea how to make it work.

Here are some settings from the sample project

[image]

As you can see there are a few frameworks it must link, there's an embedded framework which is provided by Vuforia in the SDK and a bunch of c++ files and headers to include.

Here's my .podspec attempt

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'Vuforia'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'Vuforia library.'

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/7681268/vuforia'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { '7681268' => '<OMITTED>@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => '<OMITTED>/vuforia/ios/pod', :tag => '0.1.0' }

  s.swift_version = '5'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '13.0'

  s.source_files = 'vuforia/Classes/**/*'

  s.library = 'c++'
  s.xcconfig = {
      #  'CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD' => 'c++11',
      #  'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY' => 'libc++',
       'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(inherited) "vuforia/CrossPlatform"',
       'CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES' => 'YES',
       'ENABLE_BITCODE' => 'NO'
  }

  s.resource_bundles = {
    'vuforia' => ['vuforia/Assets/*']
  }

  s.vendored_frameworks = 'VuforiaEngine.framework'
  s.frameworks = 'Foundation', 'QuartzCore', 'CoreMedia', 'MediaPlayer', 'VuforiaEngine', 'UIKit', 'AudioToolbox', 'SystemConfiguration', 'CoreMotion', 'CoreGraphics',  'CoreFoundation', 'Security', 'AVFoundation','Metal'
  s.public_header_files = 'vuforia/Classes/**/*.h'
end
```

Files:

```
<POD ROOT>
  +_pods.xcodeproj
  +Example
  -vuforia
    +Assets (contains the models, textures, vuforia database)
    +Classes (some swift code for the UI, and a C++ wrapper)
    +CrossPlatform (Contains the crossplatform c++ bridge between the sample and the framework)
  +VuforiaEngine.framework (Framework provided by Vuforia)
  Vuforia.podspec
```

After linting the project I have error messages originated from the Fundation framework .

**Edit:** This part has been resolved by renaming the the VuforiaWrapper.cpp to '.mm' extension

```
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:523:1: error: expected unqualified-id
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:525:9: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:526:9: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:528:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:529:44: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:531:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:532:53: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:534:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:534:50: error: unknown type name 'Protocol'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:535:19: error: unknown type name 'Protocol'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:535:61: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:539:30: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:539:53: error: format argument not an NSString
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:540:31: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:540:63: error: format argument not an NSString
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:9:1: error: expected unqualified-id
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:19:63: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:20:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
- ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:10:1: error: expected unqualified-id
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

The error originates from the VuforiaWrapper.h file which contains this line:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

#### Questions

Is there any solution to include these settings in the CocoaPods workspace manually (like I've done with a new project prom scratch without CocoaPods)?

If not, how to properly configure the podspec to achieve the same?

Is there any other / better approach?

Note: I'm looking for the simplest solution but feel free to suggest more robust methods for the future. Also, I'm not planning to publish this pod, I just would like to make it work somehow with my project

Xcode version: **13.2.1**

OS: **macOS Big Sur 11.6.3**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Ionic is integrated with Cordova, so maybe try use plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-vuforia-sdk

Comment: I saw this but I have two problems: #1 it's 6 years old and I doubt it works with the sample code and recent versions of the the frameworks, #2 I had other problems with cordova so I dropped this approach earlier. But thanks for the suggestion